# Drupal 7 - Fivestar and Userpoints

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, userpoints, fivestar

i have a content type and the possibility for logged in users to vote on it. there are 5 different fivestar votings (categories) on the node. now i want to add userpoints and wanted to ask if it is possible that when a user votes that he gets 1 point for every vote on a node, so 5 points if he votes in every category. he has the possibility to change the vote later, but then he shouldn´t get any points anymore. is this possible?

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it doesn't look like there is an existing 7.x or 8.x module that accomplishes this, there are two ways you should be able to accomplish your goal:

- **Write a module.** The [Userpoints API is fairly well-documented](https://drupal.org/node/206558) and it should be possible to create a module to increment a user's userpoint count when a fivestar field is modified. To avoid duplication, note that this field looks like it should accomplish the de-duping you are looking for (assuming you set `txn_id` to some combination of the current node ID, field ID, and user ID:

`'txn_id'      => (int) Transaction ID of a current points record. If
                         present an UPDATE occurs`

- **Use Rules.** The userpoints module integrates with Rules, so you should be able to accomplish your userpoints use case without writing any code. According tho the [Userpoints Rules integration notes](https://drupal.org/node/874376), you can compare the current userpoints to the number of points before the transaction:

`Compare Userpoints before the transaction
- This condition is used to compare the amount of userpoints the user had before the userpoints was added to/deducted from the user against a specified value.
- The 'Amount to compare' value is checked as >= (greater than or equal to) and the Negate checkbox will change the condition to < (less than) as it will be any value other than >=. If you would like to get an exact value, say 1, you can add two of the condition to use >= and < to specify one number. Simple math stuff here =)`

I hope this helps. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, my PHP knowledge is very small, so i will try to do it with Rules.